# Why are all dependency in go.mod indirect?

Tags: go, go-modules

I initialise a go project by running:

```
go mod init firstgo_app
```

I confirmed the module was created:

```
cat go.mod
module firstgo_app

go 1.18
```

Then I installed a dependency on github.com/gin-gonic/gin by executing

```
get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

after which I viewed the content of `go.mod` and this time it looks like this:

```
cat go.mod
module firstgo_app

go 1.18

require (
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.7 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.13.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.17.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.3 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.9 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180228061459-e0a39a4cb421 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v0.0.0-20180701023420-4b7aa43c6742 // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.1.7 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20200622213623-75b288015ac9 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.8 // indirect
)
```

What I do not get is the fact that all the dependency has been tagged as *indirect*. My understanding is that it is only transitive dependency that are tagged *indirect* but the dependency I directly depend upon should not be tagged as such. That is `github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.7 // indirect` should not have the *indirect* tag since this is the dependency I specifically downloaded.

I thought this was the case because I am not directly using the dependency, so I recreated the module again but also created a `main.go` file where I explicitly depend on `gonic/gin`:

```
cat main.go
package main
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                        "message": "pong",
                })
        })
        r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

When I try to build it fails with:

```
go build
main.go:2:8: no required module provides package github.com/gin-gonic/gin; to add it:
    go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

but when I run `go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin` and then build, all the dependency in `go.mod` are still tagged indirect.

So what gives? What am I missing here? Or do I understand the *indirect* wrongly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The `indirect` comment indicates a dependency is not used directly by your module, only indirectly by other module dependencies.

When you first run `go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin`, the module will be downloaded, but since you don't use it, it will still be marked `indirect`.

When you start using it, it will no longer be `indirect`, but `go build` does not update `go mod` automatically.

Run `go mod tidy`, and then it will not be marked `indirect` anymore.

```
$ go mod tidy
$ cat go.mod
module firstgo_app

go 1.18

require github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.7

require (
        github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
        github.com/go-playground/locales v0.13.0 // indirect
        github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.17.0 // indirect
        github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.4.1 // indirect
        github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.3 // indirect
        github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.9 // indirect
        github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.0 // indirect
        github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12 // indirect
        github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180228061459-e0a39a4cb421 // indirect
        github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v0.0.0-20180701023420-4b7aa43c6742 // indirect
        github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.1.7 // indirect
        golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20200622213623-75b288015ac9 // indirect
        golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42 // indirect
        gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.8 // indirect
)
```

This has been since [Go 1.14](https://go.dev/doc/go1.14):

> go commands other than `go mod tidy` no longer edit the `go.mod` file if the changes are only cosmetic.

Comment: I had the same question, and your answer worked great for me, thanks for the explanation.